# how to refresh the page without reloading, using django, ajax, jQuery?

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to delete products from cart without refreshing the entire page, I can delete an item and then I need to reload the page to delete another item. I am using Django, jQuery and AJAX  to attain the desired result after going through questions of similar nature. In another branch I have implemented the auto refresh feature, whereby after deletion the page automatically reloads but it is not a great user experience.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

here's my views.py delete item from cart function

```
def delete_item_from_cart(request):
    cart_total_amt = 0
    product_id = str(request.GET['id'])
    if 'cart_data_obj' in request.session:
        if product_id in request.session['cart_data_obj']:
            cart_data = request.session['cart_data_obj']
            del request.session['cart_data_obj'][product_id]
            request.session['cart_data_obj'] = cart_data

    if 'cart_data_obj' in request.session:
        for p_id, item in request.session['cart_data_obj'].items():
            cart_total_amt += int(item['qty']) * float(item['price'])
    
    context = render_to_string("core/async/cart-list.html", {"cart_data":request.session['cart_data_obj'], 'totalCartItems':len(request.session['cart_data_obj']), 'cart_total_amount':cart_total_amt})
    return JsonResponse({"data":context, "totalCartItems":len(request.session['cart_data_obj'])})
```

here's my function.js implementation

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete-product").on("click", function(){
        let product_id = $(this).attr("data-product")
        let this_val = $(this)
        console.log(product_id);
        console.log(this_val);
    
        $.ajax({
            url:'/delete-from-cart',
            data:{
                'id':product_id
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                console.log("IN before send");
                this_val.hide()
                console.log("IN after send");
            },
            success: function(response){
                console.log("Starting success");
                this_val.show()
                $("#cart-items-count").text(response.totalCartItems)
                $("#cart-list").html(response.data)
                console.log("successfully removed");
            },
            error: function(response){
                alert('error');
            }
        })
    })
})
```

To be able to delete the next item in the cart without refreshing the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try attaching the event listener higher in the DOM via event delegation, it'd attach a single event listener to the parent element and would then run for any existing, or future `.data-product` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // for example
    $("#cart-list").on("click", ".delete-product", function() {
        // same code here
    })
})
```

This might help by attaching the click event listener to the `#cart-list` and by adding the `.delete-product` selector to any new `.delete-product` elements, fixing the issue of having to refresh because the event listener goes missing?

Reference:

- https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler